# How to produce infrasound without electrical technology?

Tags: technology, telecommunications

So in my story there is this huge development whereby a technology is figured out to provide telecommunications via infrasound, like elephants. I was told that elephants can communicate long distances using infrasound propagating through the ground, which they can sense with their feet.

Is there anyway at all that infrasound can be reliably generated and controlled for the purposes of telecommunications using non-electric and non-electronic technology? Any historical age is valid, from stone age to rennaissence, the simpler the better, as long as it can be generated and detectable at long distance and **does not employ electricity in any capacity**.

I was thinking about communication through the ground but I have no problems with communication through the air, if it is at all possible. I thought about the ground because I assumed the speed of sound would be higher at the ground and the dissipation would be smaller, because the medium is not very elastic. That and the elephants of course.

Comment: Don't elephants use their voices for this?

Comment: I don't know. You would think so, right? But the article on Wikipedia says that they detect it with their feet. I thought this would be an odd thing to add if the sound had been generate in the air via their voices.

Answer (score 1):

The question asks how to *generate* infrasounds. Fortunately, it does not ask how to detect them...

Producing infrasounds is easy -- just use an ordinary musical instrument sized appropriately. For example, an ordinary [monochord](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monochord) sized to produce $\text{C}_{-1}$ (about 8 Hz, 5 octaves bellow $\text{C}_4$ a.k.a. middle C). Easy peasy.

<sup>The frequency produced by the same string under the same tension is inversely proportional to the length of the string. Tune your monochord to produce middle C (around 261 Hz) when plucked; a string 32 times longer will then produce $\text{C}_{-1}$, about 8 Hz, which is infrasonic.</sup>

*Detecting* the infrasounds is trickier, because you cannot hear them, and other senses don't work unless the infrasounds are really really strong.

Comment: Indeed yes. Detecting low frequency sound is a challenge even with electronics.

Comment: The detection is kind of magical so it's cool. One thing though, would infrasound generated like that have a higher range than a higher frequency sound of equal intensity?

Comment: That might be a separate question, @urquiza -- about the carrying qualities of infrasounds vs. audible sound, or carrying quality vs. frequency.  Likely this is connected with why nearby thunder has a bright "crack" while distant thunder is just a rumble...

Comment: That is nice for transportation through air. But what about transportation through the ground? How could I do it?  What about voice could I make a "megaphone" for infrasound?

Comment: Indeed, the octobass https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octobass has a C0 fundamental